# Ionic3-How to set next/pervious button functions in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Currently I developing a new Mobile Musical App

I need some help

How to set next/pervious button function in ionic3 framework

When user click next button,then next song will need to play.In the same way, if user click pervious button,then pervious songs will need to play.

Here I added My code

**`albumname.html`**

```
<ion-footer>

<audio-track #audioTrack [track]="currentTrack" [autoplay]="true" 
(onFinish)="onTrackFinished($event)">

<div style="display: flex;position: relative;top: 27px;">

<button clear  (click)="change()">
<ion-icon name="pause" *ngIf="!visible" (click)="audioTrack.pause()"></ion- 
icon>
<ion-icon name="play" *ngIf="visible" (click)="audioTrack.canPlay ? 
audioTrack.play() : next()"></ion-icon>
</button>

<audio-track-progress-bar duration progress [audioTrack]="audioTrack" 
style="width: 100%; margin: 0 10px;color: white"></audio-track-progress-bar>
</div>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; height: 50px;">
<div *ngIf="audioTrack">
<h4>{{ audioTrack?.artist }}</h4> 
 </div>
<ion-spinner *ngIf="audioTrack && audioTrack.isLoading"></ion-spinner>
</div>
</audio-track>

 <ion-icon name="ios-fastforward-outline" (click)="next()"></ion- 
icon>
<ion-icon name="ios-rewind-outline"></ion-icon>

 </ion-footer>
```

**`albumname.ts`**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, Platform, IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, 
ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic- 
native/streaming-media';
import { TabsnewPage } from '../tabsnew/tabsnew';
import { ITrackConstraint } from 'ionic-audio';
import { AlbumPage } from '../album/album'
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-albumname',
templateUrl: 'albumname.html',
 })
export class AlbumnamePage {

myTracks: ITrackConstraint[];
playlist: ITrackConstraint[] = [];

currentIndex: number = -1;
currentTrack: ITrackConstraint;

visible = false;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, private streamingMedia: 
StreamingMedia,   public platform: Platform, private _cdRef: 
ChangeDetectorRef, public modalCtrl: ModalController,private socialSharing: 
 SocialSharing) {

 this.myTracks = [{
 src: 'https://archive.org/download/JM2013-10-05.flac16/V0/jm2013-10-05-t12- 
 MP3-V0.mp3',
  artist: 'John Mayer',
 title: 'Why Georgia',
 art: 'assets/imgs/banner1.jpeg',
 preload: 'metadata' // tell the plugin to preload metadata such as 
 duration for this track, set to 'none' to turn off
 },
{
src: 'https://archive.org/download/JM2013-10-05.flac16/V0/jm2013-10-05- 
t12-MP3-V0.mp3',
 artist: 'Mercy-Badshah Feat',
 title: 'Lauren Gottlieb',
 art: 'assets/imgs/banner1.jpeg',
preload: 'metadata' // tell the plugin to preload metadata such as 
duration for this track, set to 'none' to turn off
},

{
src: 'https://archive.org/download/JM2013-10-05.flac16/V0/jm2013-10-05- 
t12-MP3-V0.mp3',
artist: 'Ahmed Chawki fest',
title: 'Pitbull',
art: 'assets/imgs/banner1.jpeg',
preload: 'metadata' // tell the plugin to preload metadata such as 
duration for this track, set to 'none' to turn off
}];       
}

change() {
this.visible = !this.visible;
}

play(track: ITrackConstraint, index: number) {
this.currentTrack = track;
this.currentIndex = index;   
}

next() {
 if (this.playlist.length > 0 && this.currentIndex >= 0 ) {
 let i = this.currentIndex + 1;
 let track = this.playlist[i];
 this.play(track, i);
 this._cdRef.detectChanges();  
 } else if (this.currentIndex == -1 && this.playlist.length > 0) {

  this.play(this.playlist[0], 0);
 }
 }     

 onTrackFinished(track: any) {
 this.next();
  }

   clear() {
   this.playlist = [];
   }

   }
```

Comment: If You know answer?help me?@Utpaul

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 buttons. One for next and other for previous. In typescript file create a global variable which keeps track of the current track I,e being played. If next is clicked then increment the index (make sure it is not exceeding your array range). On click of previous decrease the current index by one(make sure it is not less than 0).

Comment: can you please help me with codes.because i'm new to ionic framework.
i added code for `next()` button but it not working.Dont know why?

Comment: Is control itself is not coming inside the next() function or required functionality is not working ?